# How to escape iframe in an Shopify embedded app that was created using Shopify CLI 2

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I am having a problem implementing the update described in this documentation by Shopify:
https://shopify.dev/apps/auth/oauth/update/node-php

Summary:

- I created my app using the [Shopify CLI version 2.26](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli)
- Running on [Node version 18.10](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v18.10.0/)
- I have installed the npm package [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom)
- I have developed my app so that the Home page toggles between other page components based on state.

The update introduces several new providers and also some file-based routing.
So when the paged needs to be redirected it calls:

```js
return res.redirect(`/exitiframe?${queryParams}`);
```

What is the best way to implement this?
Do I add the code from the Exitiframe.jsx file to my HomePage.jsx and edit the link to:

```js
return res.redirect(`/?${queryParams}`);
```

I have tried and I get an endless loop.